# How does npm dedupe the dependencies of different versions of a dependency?

Tags: node.js, npm

To explain my question a bit better I have a simplified version of a dependency tree:

```
A --> B@1.0.0 --> D@1.0.0 --> E@1.0.0
A --> C@1.0.0 --> D@2.0.0 --> E@1.0.0

Legend:
=======
A: Root component
B & C: Dependencies of A
D: Components that are not deduped, because of different major versions.
E: Components that in my opinion should be deduped, but aren't.
```

**Why is component E not being deduped?**

I'm using npm@2.9.0

Comment: FWIW `npm dedupe` doesn't seem to do anything, even when I run it in a project with several of duplicate modules with identical version numbers. I don't really get it. It doesn't seem to work as documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fix for this is coming in [NPM 3](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v3.0.0). Use the beta and see if it fixes your issue.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Specifically the [multi-stage feature](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/98233700815/multi-stage-installs-and-a-better-npm) fixes this.